# Generalization of a class constructor with interface (.Net Framework 4.8)

Tags: c#

Simplifying the question, I have these 2 functions

```
private void ReadFilesCommon(List<string> input)
{
    foreach (string entry in input)
    {
        new Class1(entry, entry.length);
    }
}
```

and

```
private void ReadFilesCommon2(List<string> input)
{
    foreach (string entry in input)
    {
        new Class2(entry);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to generalize these functions?

My main problem is the different inputs, but putting that aside, is it possible with interfaces?

Something like

```
private void ReadFilesCommon2(IClass Class)
{
    foreach ()
    {
        new Class(input1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You question is a little too generic/vauge. What does your `foreach` loop do with the `class` objects it instatiates? How much of the code is repated vs unique/depedant on the class it is working with (i.e. `Class1` vs `Class2`)?

Comment: Class1 is completely different from Class2 and the foreach doesnt interact with the Class only with the input

Comment: you can try to define an interface that both Class1 and Class2 implement, and then pass an instance of that interface to the generalized function.

Comment: you're telling me that i should make the constructer as a function and use it with the interface.

Comment: How are the `inputs` provided, where do they come from? Your question is still too vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factory method/interface seem to be what you are looking for:

```
private void ReadFiles<T>(List<string> input, Func<string, T> creator)
{
    foreach (string entry in input)
    {
        var item = creator(entry);
    }
}

// and replace your functions with:
ReadFiles(input, s => new Class1(s)); // ReadFilesCommon
ReadFiles(input, s => new Class2(s, s.Length)); // ReadFilesCommon1
```